Can one convert a PhotosPickerItem to a string and then later convert the string back in order to access the image from the gallery
I have an Android app that I am attempting to port to iOS. In the Android app, I associate an image from the photo gallery with a person's name. I do this by, after having chosen the appropriate image, converting the image's URI to a string and saving it in my database. Then later, when I selected that person, I convert the string back to a URI and use it to access the appropriate image in the photo gallery. In all of the threads that I have seen so far, people are trying to save the actual image somewhere in order to recall it later. I don't want to do that since the image is already in the gallery. In SwiftUI, is it possible to convert a PhotosPickerItem value to a string, and later, convert that string back to a PhotosPickerItem in order to access the image in the photo gallery?

No "PhotosPickerItem" is just a temporary container. if you have proper permissions you can get the id and then request the PHAsset https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78775085/swiftui-photospicker-get-the-size-of-picked-item-in-kilobytes/78775333#78775333 which has the ability to do so much more.

Thank you.  That is what I was trying to find.
